# How to open port for specific IP?

Tags: node.js, macos, express, command-line-interface, firewall

Using Mac OS, how to open port (3005) to specific IP, so only that IP can access it, using CLI and firewall? Doing on Linux Ubuntu server I am using the UFW service which is simple. How to do the same thing using MacOS with Nodejs app using express?

Answer (score 1):

> Mac OS X 10.6 (and earlier) came with IPFW, a port of FreeBSD’s
>   stateful firewall[1]. IPFW was deprecated in OS X 10.7, and was
>   completely removed in OS X 10.10; it was replaced with PF. PF (Packet
>   Filter) is OpenBSD’s system for filtering TCP/IP traffic and doing
>   Network Address Translation[2]. PF in OS X, however, appears to be
>   based on the FreeBSD port of PF[3], but with some notable additions
>   (see below). Like FreeBSD 9.X and later, OS X appears to use the same
>   version of PF as OpenBSD 4.5. Note that the latest OpenBSD version is
>   5.6 (as of January 2015);and the configuration syntax for PF changed around 4.6/4.7.

https://robert-chalmers.uk/2018/10/03/protect-your-mac-with-pf-the-all-powerful-firewall/